# How to save array of data pages in hexo from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, hexo

I'm trying to build a site with [Hexo](https://hexo.io/api/posts.html) from list of pages from an array of objects instead a folder.

I'd like to use hexo just because I don't want to reinvent the wheel and because it seems to be very handful, but I didn't got how to pass a json object and save in a `site` folder.

```
var data = {
    title: 'Buttons',
    name: 'block-name',
    category: 'Category name / Sub category',
    description: 'This is the description of the element\n and you can write text just like this.',
    otherProperty: 'Hello'
};

hexo = new Hexo(process.cwd(), {
    debug: true,
    config: '_config.yml'
});
hexo.init().then(function(){
    hexo.post.create(data, false);
});
```

The api `hexo.post.create` creates the source files, not the final html file, I'm not sure if this is possible and how I can tell to Hexo how to do it.

Basically, I would pass the `data` to the template I'll use to create the pages, is that possible?

Comment: Hi, could you give more details, please? You just wanna generate some html page (the same) from data stored in an array, that's right?

Comment: sure, I've also opened an issue on github: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1556